# Why does this UnboundLocalError occur (closure)?

Tags: python, scope, closures, global-variables

What am I doing wrong here?

```
counter = 0

def increment():
  counter += 1

increment()
```

The above code throws an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: This question and the one it's currently marked duplicate of are under discussion in the [Python chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34899645#34899645).

Comment: Many of the answers here say to use `global`, and although that works, using modifiable globals is generally _not_ recommend when other options exist.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus A question asked in 2012 can't be a duplicate of a question asked in 2016 ... rather the newer one is the duplicate.

Comment: @dsh [That's not true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is though the general issue is *closing over* and updating a binding which is not local. UnboundLocalError can also occur for fully local variables but they're a different issue (with a different solution).

Comment: @Masklinn yes, but a *closure is not created in this case*. You can check, `print(increment.__closure__)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's an implementation detail. It's conceptually a closure, even if Python differentiates globals and non-global nonlocals. The question and primary answer is relevant to the issue either way.

Comment: @Masklinn OK, you've convinced me. I guess in the broadest sense a free variable is any non-local variable. Feel free to rollback

Comment: See also: [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Python doesn't have variable declarations, so it has to figure out the [scope](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) of variables itself.  It does so by a simple rule:  If there is an assignment to a variable inside a function, that variable is considered local.<sup>[[1]](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)</sup>  Thus, the line

```
counter += 1
```

implicitly makes `counter` local to `increment()`.  Trying to execute this line, though, will try to read the value of the local variable `counter` before it is assigned, resulting in an [`UnboundLocalError`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#UnboundLocalError).<sup>[[2]](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)</sup>

If `counter` is a global variable, the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) keyword will help.  If `increment()` is a local function and `counter` a local variable, you can use [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) in Python 3.x.

Comment: python 3 docs has a [faq page on why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) via [unboundlocalerror-local-variable-l-referenced-before-assignment-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456739/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-l-referenced-before-assignment-python)

Comment: A note that caught me out, I had a variable declared at the top of the file that I can read inside a function without issue, however to write to a variable that I have declared at the top of the file, I had to use global.

Comment: A more in-depth explanation: https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding. Not only can assignments bind names, so can imports, so you may also get `UnboundLocalError` from a statement that uses an unbounded imported name. Example: `def foo(): bar = deepcopy({'a':1}); from copy import deepcopy; return bar`, then `from copy import deepcopy; foo()`. The call  succeeds if the local import `from copy import deepcopy` is removed.

Answer (score 95):

You need to use the [global statement](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) so that you are modifying the global variable counter, instead of a local variable:

```
counter = 0

def increment():
  global counter
  counter += 1

increment()
```

If the enclosing scope that `counter` is defined in is not the global scope, on Python 3.x you could use the [nonlocal statement](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement).  In the same situation on Python 2.x you would have no way to reassign to the nonlocal name `counter`, so you would need to make `counter` mutable and modify it:

```
counter = [0]

def increment():
  counter[0] += 1

increment()
print counter[0]  # prints '1'
```

Answer (score 30):

To answer the question in your subject line,* yes, there are closures in Python, except they only apply inside a function, and also (in Python 2.x) they are read-only; you can't re-bind the name to a different object (though if the object is mutable, you can modify its contents). In Python 3.x, you can use the [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=nonlocal#nonlocal) keyword to modify a closure variable.

```
def incrementer():
    counter = 0
    def increment():
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
        return counter
    return increment

increment = incrementer()

increment()   # 1
increment()   # 2
```

* The question origially asked about closures in Python.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why your code throws an `UnboundLocalError` is already well explained in other answers.

But it seems to me that you're trying to build something that works like [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

So try it out, and see if it suits your case:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> counter = count(0)
>>> counter
count(0)
>>> next(counter)
0
>>> counter
count(1)
>>> next(counter)
1
>>> counter
count(2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Python has lexical scoping by default, which means that although an enclosed scope can access values in its enclosing scope, it cannot modify them (unless they're declared global with the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) keyword).

A closure binds values in the *enclosing* environment to names in the *local* environment. The local environment can then use the bound value, and even reassign that name to something else, but it can't modify the binding in the enclosing environment.

In your case you are trying to treat `counter` as a local variable rather than a bound value. Note that this code, which binds the value of `x` assigned in the enclosing environment, works fine:

```
>>> x = 1

>>> def f():
>>>  return x

>>> f()
1
```

Answer (score 3):

To modify a global variable inside a function, you must use the global keyword.

When you try to do this without the line

```
global counter
```

inside of the definition of increment, a local variable named counter is created so as to keep you from mucking up the counter variable that the whole program may depend on.

Note that you only need to use global when you are modifying the variable; you could read counter from within increment without the need for the global statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
counter = 0

def increment():
  global counter
  counter += 1

increment()
```

Answer (score -2):

Python is not purely lexically scoped.

See *[Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them/)*.

And *[Notes on Python variable scope](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/)*.