# Python Threads 'While' not Behaving

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, increment

Okay. So I'm trying to make 2 threads to run and increment a value so it knows when to stop. I'm kind of lost, because I'm new to Python, and everything looks right to me..

```
import threading;
import socket;
import time;

count = 0;

class inp(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while count < 11:
            time.sleep(0.5);
            print("Thread 1!");
            count += 1;

class recv_oup(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while count < 31:
            time.sleep(0.5);
            print("Thread 2!");
            count += 1;

inp().start();
recv_oup().start();
```

And the error is quite long...

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "core.py", line 9, in run
    while count < 11:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "core.py", line 16, in run
    while count < 31:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

I have no clue what's happening. As I said, new to Python, so this is all gibberish to me. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: FYI, in Python you generally don't end statements with semicolons.

Comment: Welcome to python - it's an amazing language!  As a tip, you don't need to terminate statements with the ';' -- statements are ended by newlines, so just hit the return key!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python)

Comment: -1: On Stack Overflow, we expect users to show a little research effort before asking a new question.  In your case, searching for the error you get (`UnboundLocalError`) should have let you to the solution in no time!

Comment: I did. I didn't find anything. That would be why I came here. Obviously not everyone can find what they're looking for, when a post is nearly 3 months old. Sorry.

Comment: You didn't find anything?  What have you been searching for?  You should really try to understand the exception traceback you get ("all gibberish").  Otherwise, you won't be able to solve *any* Python errors you get by your own.  The exception message is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment".  Pasting this in your favorite search engine would have given you the answer right away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, if you want to modify a global variable, you need to use the `global` keyword:

```
class inp(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global count
        while count < 11:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Thread 1!")
            count += 1
```

Otherwise, Python will treat `count` as a local variable and optimize access to it.  This way, the *local* `count` is not defined yet in the while loop.

Also, get rid of the semicolons, they are not needed in Python!

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare that you intend to use the global count, not create a new local variable: Add `global count` to the run methods in both of your threads.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are modifying the value of count, you'll need to declare it as global

```
class inp(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global count
        while count < 11:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Thread 1!")
            count += 1

class recv_oup(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global count
        while count < 31:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Thread 2!")
            count += 1
```