# Python error. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, json, terminal, httplib

I'm so lost as to what I'm doing wrong... I've searched the net for a few hours now, tried to reformat my code a bunch, and now I just feel stuck.

This is my code:

```
import httplib
import json

urlBase = 'amoeba.im'
token = False
username = raw_input('Username? ')

connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(urlBase)

def get(url):
    connection.request("GET", url)
    response = connection.getresponse()
    print response.status, response.reason
    print response.read();
    if token == False:
        token = response.read()
        token = token.split('"token":"')[1]
        token = token.split('","')[0]
        print token

get('/api/login?username=' + username)

get('/api/rooms/join?room=#lobby&token=' + token)

get('/api/postmessage?message=hello%20world&token=' + token)

connection.close()
```

Here's the terminal output:

```
Tyler-Keohanes-MacBook-Pro:~ tylerkeohane$ clear && '/usr/bin/pythonw' '/Users/tylerkeohane/Desktop/chatbot.py'
Username? TgwizBot
200 OK
{"success":true,"username":"TgwizBot","token":"103f6a2809eafb6","users":[{"username":"razerwolf","seen":1338582178260},{"username":"tonynoname","seen":1338582178028},{"username":"arrum","seen":1338582177804},{"username":"Valerio","seen":1338582177504},{"username":"Tgwizman","seen":1338582177258},{"username":"tonynoname2","seen":1338582178004},{"username":"TgwizBot","seen":1338582182219}],"time":1338582182219}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tylerkeohane/Desktop/chatbot.py", line 21, in <module>
    get('/api/login?username=' + username)
  File "/Users/tylerkeohane/Desktop/chatbot.py", line 15, in get
    if token == False:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'token' referenced before assignment
Tyler-Keohanes-MacBook-Pro:~ tylerkeohane$
```

Can anyone help? :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python)

Comment: I'll add that if you google "unboundlocalerror", [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/) is the first result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The clue is here:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'token' referenced before assignment
```

You need to declare `token` as a global:

```
def get(url):
    global token
    ...
```

You might also want to consider avoiding global variables as they are generally regarded as a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You assign to `token` in your function, so it is considered a local variable to that function. As the error message indicates, you have tried to use it before there is anything in it.

The `token` that you have declared outside the function is "hidden" by the local variable so it is not accessible.

To make it assignable in your function, put `global token` just after the `def` line.

But global variables are usually a sign of a bad design. Instead you should probably be passing `token` into the function as an argument.

You will find life a lot easier if you just use the [`requests`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python-requests.org%2Fen%2Flatest%2Fpy-modindex%2F&ei=mSjJT4HvNsOC2AW1pIDaCw&usg=AFQjCNFqp0ERbYnWckemaReEDbso5Ue2cw&sig2=_BQT4C_tqxnoWqYot8a9gw) module.