# local variable referenced before assignment for decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I'm using decorator with the functional syntax as it's described [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax).

I loop over a list of dict. In this loop I wrap a generic function with a decorator taking a parameter. Then i call the wrapped function with the current dict as parameters.

My problem is that i get an `local variable 'generic_evaluator' referenced before assignment` error.

Here is my code:

**The concerned decorator:**

```
def log(logfile_name):
    def inner_log(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            import os
            ret = func()
            # business code...
        return wraps(func)(wrapped)
    return inner_log
```

And here the place where I wrap `generic_evaluator` function with the `log` decorator.

```
for evaluation in generic_evaluations:
    generic_evaluator = log(evaluation['suffix'])(generic_evaluator)
    generic_evaluator(evaluation['suffix'], evaluation['id'])
```

**EDIT**

It'll be probably more clear with this piece of code in addition:

```
@tictoc
def generic_evaluator(suffix_url, id):
    xml = etree.parse(get_resource(base_url + "/" + suffix_url + "/" + str(id)))
    links = fetch_urls_from_xml(xml)
    return links
```

Comment: Why do you think it should work. Here: `log(evaluation['suffix'])(generic_evaluator)` you are using `generic_evaluator`, which is not yet assigned. Hence the error. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `generic_evaluator` is a global function, and you actually want to rebind the global name `generic_evaluator`, declare this name as global:

```
global generic_evaluator
```

If you don't want to rebind the global name, use a different local name and initialise it:

```
local_generic_evaluator = generic_evaluator
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python/9264845#9264845) gives an explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
generic_evaluator = log(evaluation['suffix'])(generic_evaluator)
```

You are referrencing generic_evaluator before assignment here log(evaluation['suffix'])(generic_evaluator)

try this:

```
for evaluation in generic_evaluations:
    generic_evaluator = log(evaluation['suffix'])(use_some_other_variable)
    generic_evaluator(evaluation['suffix'], evaluation['id'])
```

Comment: I forgot to precise that ``generic_evaluator`` is already defined. (See my EDIT)

Comment: @renard you ve problem wit this line generic_evaluator = log(evaluation['suffix'])(generic_evaluator)

Comment: It's not another variable i need to use. It is a function object i use here, and it's a function already defined as i said in my edit.

Comment: @renard, `ev = log(evaluation['suffix'])(generic_evaluator)` good for you? or cascade wrapping of generic_evaluator is needed?