# "UnboundLocalError: local variable" but variable is a global

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I followed a queue example from the bottom of the [Python Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) page. I want to access some global variables within the worker function, however, some globals are accessible and some aren't. In my simple example below, the 'rows' and 'errors' variables are accessible but then I get UnboundLocalError for count. If i put "global count" then it works. But I don't understand why the other globals are accessible.

```
File "myfile.py", line 184, in dpn_worker
    count += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the code example I used:

```
dpns = [1,2,3,4]
q = Queue.Queue()
rows = []
errors = []
count = 0

def dpn_worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        rows.append(1)
        errors.append(1)
        count += 1
        q.task_done()

def main():
    for d in dpns:
        q.put(d)

    for i in range(NUM_WORKERS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=dpn_worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    q.join()
```

Comment: Pasting the question title into the search box gives http://stackoverflow.com/q/9264763/395760 as very first result. Is a tiny bit of research really that hard? -1

Comment: Sorry, I actually did search at first. Guess my google-fu failed me this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since count is an integer: -

```
count += 1
```

is equivalent to

```
count = count + 1
```

So, you are trying to modify the global variable, but are actually creating a local one.. But on the RHS, you are using the local variable before initialization..

Modify your **dpn_worker** as: -

```
def dpn_worker():
    global count
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        rows.append(1)
        errors.append(1)
        count += 1
        q.task_done()
```

Comment: Nope, it's not precisely equivalent. In-place addition can have, and in the case of some collections, has different semantics from "regular" addition.

Comment: @delnan.. OK.. Is it defined somewhere, in what condition they are different?? Actually I have started coding in Python just a few days back..

Comment: @RohitJain one example can be lists, for lists `+=` works as `extend()` and `lis =lis +somelis` actually creates a new list(`lis+somelis`) and then assigns it to `lis` on the LHS.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. Then what happens to the original list in second case?? Garbage Collected?

Comment: @RohitJain Potentially, but it could have other names, which would still contain the original list. If you did ``a = [1, 2]`` then ``b = a``, then ``a = a + [3]``, ``a`` would be ``[1, 2, 3]`` while ``b`` would be ``[1, 2]``. If you did ``a += [3]``, both would be ``[1, 2, 3]``.

Comment: @Lattyware.. Yeah that is what we call `Reference Count`..

Comment: if it's refcount is 0 then yes it is GC.

Comment: @RohitJain I know, I was just specifying that it was the case - it is not safe to assume that it will be garbage collected. For one, in some other implementation, it could not happen for any reason (as Python doesn't specify how garbage collection should be done) and that other references could still exist. This can be a gotcha.

Comment: Yeah.. That is somewhat similar to Java.. Of course, garbage collection is completely out of our control..  Thanks @Lattyware...  :)

Comment: @Lattyware.. One more question.. What book should I refer for Python??

Comment: @RohitJain python even caches strings and small integers, which you may not find in Java. For books you can try http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-book-for-learning-Python-as-a-beginner and http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/What-are-the-best-books-for-learning-Python

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. Thanks for the link.. Actually, Java also caches string literals, and integer till some range, which is different on different JVMs.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Actually that list I have seen on many websites, but couldn't decide which one to grab... Currently I have started reading `Core Python Programming`..

Comment: @RohitJain I learned from `core python programmming `too and also  `learning python`(mark lutz). But I learned about most of the cool and advanced stuff on SO itself.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. Yeah you're right.. There is lot to learn on SO.. Thanks :)