# Best way to use module local variables in functions that modify their value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

This is in Python 2.7.  Here's an example.

```
v = 1

def print_v():
    v += 1
    print v

print_v()
```

How can this be rewritten that when this module is imported, I don't get this:

```
$ python -c "import the_above_module"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "the_above_module.py", line 9, in <module>
    print_v()
  File "the_above_module.py", line 6, in print_v
    v += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Search for `[python]UnboundLocalError`. Or click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9264845/1217270), [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#core-language), or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/423379/1217270).

Comment: I looked at a few, but somehow missed those.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `global v` inside your `print_v` function.

However, you should think about why you're using (and modifying) a global variable.  It is often a fragile way to do things.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a StringIO instance that's written to by other scripts of the module, and I want to keep a consistent reference available.  The main module file only handles the reference to the StringIO, resetting it, and returning the value.  Any recommendations on how else to do it?