# Python weird variable scope issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

I have my code as below.

```
def test():
   print num1
   print num
   num += 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
   num = 0
   num1 = 3
   test()
```

When executing the above python code I get the following output.

```
3 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in test
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment
```

I do not know why particularly num is not available in test method. It is very weird for me and i did not face this yet before.

Note: I am using python 2.7.

Comment: Assuming you indent properly, this code works. Please check again that you show the exact code that throws this error, you may have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @delnan I used the num variable in a place as in my last edit. Hope it makes the error in the code. Can you look the above code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python)

Comment: See, now it's easy. If you'd had included the right code (or even just the exception message) from the start, you would have gotten your answer an hour sooner ;-)

Comment: Cool, your edit brought me a downvote because my answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @phresnel I downvoted your answer, *before* the edit, because I didn't think it was useful for the question as of back then.

Comment: @delnan: I think you mean my wrong wrong answer. I provided another one which pointed out the incorrect indendation, it was roughly "After correcting the indendation, it works (http://ideone.com/wNRgCF ):". The downvotes on my first answer, which you commented on, were absolutely justified.

Comment: @phresnel No, I downvoted your other answer as well. It should have been a comment, and in fact someone had already said the same thing in the comments.

Comment: @delnan: _Imho_, under the assumption the OP pasted his code 1:1, my newer answer was valid. However, one (cannot|can forever) discuss opinion of course ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` appears in an assignment statement inside the definition of the `test`. This makes `num` a local variable. Since scope determination is made at compile time, `num` is a local  variable even in the `print` statement that precedes the assignment. At that time, `num` has no value, resulting in the error. You need to declare `num` as global if you want to access the global value. `num1` does not have this problem, since you never try to assign to it.

```
def test():
    global num
    print num1
    print num
    num += 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're assigning to `num` inside the `test` function, python considers it to be a local variable. This is why it complains that you are referencing to a local variable before assigning it.

You can fix this by explicitly declaring `num` to be global:

```
def test():
    global num
    print num1
    print num
    num += 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 0
    num1 = 3
    test()
```