# When does Python recognize/not recognize variables from main?

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, python-internals

When (if at all) do functions recognize variables that have been initialized in the `main` function?

E.g.: When I write the following Python code:

```
def plus():
    variable += 1

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    variable = 1
    plus()
```

I get the following error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'variable' referenced before assignment`

However, when I do something similar, but with a `dictionary`:

```
def plus():
    dic[1] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dic = {}
    dic[1] = 1
    plus()
    print dic[1]
```

The output is : `2`

What's the difference between the two cases?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value? There are lots of questions on SO already explaining Python scope generally and `UnboundLocalError` specifically.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795943/referencing-global-primitives-vs-objects-in-python/27796098

Comment: This has been asked at least a thousand times here and elsewhere. Also and for the record, your question is wrongly worded ("variables that have been initialized in the main function") - you don't have any "main" function here, just a top-level branch.

Comment: OK I apologize to all of those who were annoyed by the question. I guess you need to know the answer in order to know how to ask the question with the right wording. Thanks of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` operator is considered as an assignment when used with **simple** variables. So, Python while parsing the function body will add `variable` in `<function_object>.func_code.co_varnames`, and due to this during runtime Python will never look for that variable in any other scope unless you had `global` or `nonlocal` declaration(Python 3 only) at the top of the function. Note that it doesn't matter if you used `variable` before using it with `+=`(see the last example), the variable is now local everywhere in the function body.

```
>>> def plus():
...     var += 1
...     
>>> dis.dis(plus)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (var)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (var)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

On the other hand, `dic[1]` is variable look-up followed by a [`BINARY_SUBSCR`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_SUBSCR)(same thing for [`LOAD_ATTR`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_ATTR) as well; you can do `x.extend([100])` but not `x+=[100]`; where `x` is a list) and as there are no assignment statements related to `dic` after that Python considers it as a either a global variable([`LOAD_GLOBAL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_GLOBAL)) or a free variable([`LOAD_DEREF`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_DEREF)) and fetches its value from there.

```
>>> def plus():
    var[0] += 1
...     
>>> dis.dis(plus)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (var)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 DUP_TOPX                 2
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             13 INPLACE_ADD         
             14 ROT_THREE           
             15 STORE_SUBSCR        
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> def plus_with_twist():
    var[0] += 1  # this will fail due to the next line
    var += 1     # Now `var` is a local variable everywhere in the function body
>>> dis.dis(plus_with_twist)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (var)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 DUP_TOPX                 2
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             13 INPLACE_ADD         
             14 ROT_THREE           
             15 STORE_SUBSCR        

  3          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (var)
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             22 INPLACE_ADD         
             23 STORE_FAST               0 (var)
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```