# Why have different when Change Lists Global and Variable Global in Python 2.7.9?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 example below, and my question is: why List `L` don't need `global` to change value like variable `V`, I think, more Safe if `L` need `global` to change

#### Example 1:

```
L=[1,2,3,4]  
V=5          
def U():
    L[1]=22
    V=55
U()
print L[1]
print V
```

#### Result 1:

```
22
5
```

#### Example 2:

```
L=[1,2,3,4]  
V=5          
def U():
    L[1]=22  
    global V   #Now V will change like L[1]
    V=55
U()
print L[1]
print V
```

#### Result 2:

```
22
55
```

Comment: Because lists are mutable but integers are immutable... See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27795943/3001761

Comment: See also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, which is a useful introduction to identifiers in Python. You *would* need `global` to reassign `L` to a completely different object, just not to mutate the object it already references.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone can explain it better than me, but when you do the following:

```
print V
```

Python knows this variable isn't defined in your functions scope, and so it checks the global scope, and prints it.

If you were to do instead

```
V=5
```

Python knows this variable isn't defined in your functions scope, so it goes ahead and creates it (now it over-shadows `V` at the global scope). **There is different behaviour between writing a variable and reading it.**

Now compare this to a list:

```
L[1]=22
```

This is similar to `print V`. Why? Because Python needs to find where L is defined in memory, and then modifies its second index. This is a `read` followed by a `write`, whereas `print V` is simply a `read` from memory.

When your operation needs to do a `read` first, it will find the reference that was defined at the outer scope, and that is why you see a difference between `V=55` and `L[1]=22`.

When your operation is a `write` first, it will create a new variable in the function scope unless you have that variable marked as a `global`. Then it will modify that `global` instead.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. `L[1] = 22` doesn't *"de-reference"* `L`, just the object that was previously referenced via `L[1]` (strictly, it decrements the object's reference count). It doesn't *"modify its data structure"* either, as such, it just puts a different reference into the appropriate slot (and increments the relevant reference count for the new object).

Comment: Reworded the answer.