# How to understand global and local scopes in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, global-variables

I am a novice in Python and wondering the situation below.

```
x = 1
def func():
    print(x)
    x = 2
    return x
```

So I got the UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment.
But if I right understand - Python read and execute code row by row.
So in first statement inside function "print(x)" it must just relay global variable x which eq. 1, but instead I got the error.
Please explain, I think it simple.

Comment: Do these help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851906/python-3-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456739/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-l-referenced-before-assignment-python and https://www.google.com/search?q=unbound+local+variable+error+python

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Comment: you have to tell python explicitly that you want `x` inside the function to refer to the global variable

Comment: Python is not executed row-by-row; CPython *compiles* all the source in a given module to byte code before executing anything in the byte-code interpreter. Other implementations may not compile anything, but that doesn't affect the semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem was explained as well in the FAQ of [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope,
> that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly
> named variable in the outer scope. Since the last statement in foo
> assigns a new value to x, the compiler recognizes it as a local
> variable. Consequently when the earlier print(x) attempts to print the
> uninitialized local variable and an error results.

Comment: Is that means that first interpreter’s operation is initializing the scope’s variables? And only after - all row by row operations?

Comment: *Statements* are executed in order, but decisions about which names are local and which are global are made when the function is *defined*, not when it is executed.