# (CLOSED) local variable 'exit' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python

I am running python 2.75 on Wing IDE

**The code:**

```
exit = False

while not exit:

    selection = int(raw_input("Press 1 to go and 0 to quit: ")
    if selection == 1:
       print("yay")
    elif selection == 0:
       print("Goodbye")
       exit = True
    else:
       print("Go away")
```

When I press 0, it says:

```
local variable 'exit' referenced before assignment
```

What is wrong?

Comment: OK, no they arent sorry , typo

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine as follows:

```
exit = False

while not exit:
    selection = int(raw_input("Press 1 to go and 0 to quit: "))       #added ) to correct syntax error
    if selection == 1:
        print("yay")
    elif selection == 0:
        print("Goodbye")
        exit = True
    else:
        print("Go away")
```

## DEMO

Comment: Congrats for your 10k rep status ;)

Comment: you can view [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tools)! and deleted answers ;)

Comment: @Downvoter, Can you please explain if there is anything wrong with my answer? Thank you.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I think some explanation is necessary. Currently, it looks like you have exactly the same code as OP. This may not be your fault, but in any case, it is good to explain *why* some code fixes a particular problem. I'm being picky, there's not much you can do to make this useful to the community anyway, given the question :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza, Thank you, I have commented the corrections

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close parens around your int()

Still, if you're using a while loop, why not simply used a break instead of a boolean? It's much cleaner. Instead of exit = True, simply type break and the loop will end.

if my understanding of what you've typed is correct, you want to end up with:

```
    while True:
      selection = int(raw_input("Press 1 to go and 0 to quit: "))
      if selection == 1:
        print("yay")
      elif selection == 0:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
      else:
        print("Go away")
```