# getting UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, scope, closures, python-2.x

I am getting getting UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment error while trying to run this code. As per LEGB rule this should run fine.

```
def xyz():
    count = 1
    def xyz_inner():
        count += 1
        print count
    xyz_inner()
    print count
```

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python Im sure there is a duplicate somewhere here

Comment: whats your python version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see  [unbound local error](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

```
def xyz():
    count = 1
    def xyz_inner():
        count += 1
        print count, locals()
    xyz_inner()
    print count

print hasattr(globals, 'count')
print hasattr(xyz, 'count')

>>> 
False
False
```

Define variable in any mutable object like `dict` or `list`(uses same reference) and update it using augmented assignment.

it works:-

```
def xyz():
    count = {'value': 1}
    def xyz_inner():
        count['value'] += 1
        print count['value'],
    xyz_inner()
    print count

xyz()
```

see [python closure for nonlocal in python2.7](http://technotroph.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/python-closures-and-the-python-2-7-nonlocal-solution/)

Comment: Note that the statement `print hasattr(xyz, 'count')` tells you that the _function_ has no `count` attribute. This is not, however, the same thing as a function call's local namespace containing the name `count`. Function attributes are entirely separate from the call namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `count` in the inner function is bound by an (augmented) assignment statement, and is therefore regarded as local to `xyz_inner()`. Consequently, the first time the code attempts to execute `count += 1` the (local) variable `count` has not previously been assigned, and so it is indeed an unbound local.

Use of `nonlocal count` inside `xyz_inner()` should rectify that problem by telling the interpreter you want to use `xyz()`'s `count` rather than creating a local.

Comment: Thanks for answer
Now i modified my code to
def xyz():
 count = 1
 def xyz_inner():
  global count
  count += 1
                print count
 xyz_inner()
 print count
It is now giving NameError: global name 'count' is not defined

however as per my understading since count has been defined in the enclosing function so this error should not come

Comment: Sadly, `global` means "in the module's namespace" not "in the lexically surrounding function's namespace", hence my suggestion to use `nonlocal`. Unfortunately I forgot that this is a Python 3 feature.

Beware using globals for inter-component communication. It really messes up your software's cohesion.