# Python -local variable '' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out some problem I have.
I have written small program just for the example here (which i'll implement the solution in the real one :) )

So,
I have 3 files
One -Which is the main 
Test -Which is the test I run
CounterTest -Which has class with def inside

One:

```
def main():
    CounterTest=1
    execfile("c:\\111\\Test.py") 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

---

Test:

```
from CounterTest import *
print "THIS IS THE TEST"
CallClass=CounterTest1()
CallClass.CounterPlus()
```

---

CounterTest:

```
class CounterTest1():
   def CounterPlus(self):
        CounterTest +=1
        print CounterTest
```

Scenario:
I run "one" which execute file Test (All this happen in main def)
In "Test" I'm calling class and def -in def we counter +1 , that was defined in "one" file.

I'm getting "local variable 'CounterTest' referenced before assignment"

I have tried everything but nothing worked

Appriciated ,

Thanks

Comment: cyclical dependencies are never a good idea. Besides, `CounterTest` has local scope.

Comment: So how can I solve this out :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of it is that you can't. If I'm understanding your process correctly you are:

1. Running `main.py`.
2. Defining the variable INSIDE a function so it's non-global

```
def main():
    CounterTest = 1  # <-- right here
```

3. Executing code from a different file

```
    execfile("...")
```

4. Which imports a THIRD file

```
from CounterTest import *
```

5. That attempts to modify a global in the first file

```
...
    CounterTest += 1
```

You can't do that. You're three levels of "nope" away from that.

1. `main.py`'s `CounterTest` isn't a global, so it's only available inside `def main`'s scope.
2. Even if it were global, `test.py` doesn't have access to `main.py`'s globals without passing them explicitly.
3. Even if you passed them explicitly (using `execfile(path, globals_dict, locals_dict)`), and they became globals inside `test.py`, `CounterTest.py` isn't allowed to see `test.py`'s globals.

You can't even monkey around with things to make that okay. You need to paramaterize values and you need to stop using globals. This whole thing SHOULD be:

```
# counter.py
class Counter(object):
    """Counter is knows how to add to itself"""
    def __init__(self, value=1):
        self.__value = value
    def increment(self):
        self.__value += 1
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value


# main.py

import counter

c = counter.Counter()  # initializes at 1

print(c.value)  # 1
c.increment()
print(c.value)  # 2

# now SHARE that instance of c!!
```

Comment: First thanks a lot for the detailed answer..I'll try you suggestion today and update here.