# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

Code1:

```py
# coding:utf-8

sum = 5

def add(x, y):
    print sum
    sum = x + y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add(7, 8)
```

When I run the code above, I got the following error:

```
ssspure:python ssspure$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    add(7, 8)
  File "test.py", line 6, in add
    print sum
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment
```

Code2:

```py
# coding:utf-8

sum = 5

def add(x, y):
    sum = x + y
    print sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add(7, 8)
```

I can run code2 successfully.

I only moved the `print sum` below "sum = x + y" statement. Why did Code1 fail but Code2 runs successfully?

Comment: # coding:utf-8

sum = 5

def add(x, y):
 sum = sum + x

if __name__ == '__main__':
 add(7, 8)

this code also get error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't understand why UnboundLocalError occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/dont-understand-why-unboundlocalerror-occurs)

Answer (score 5):

For code1:

You didn't declare sum. The sum you defined outside of the add function has no impact to the sum in you add function.

You can just put sum=0 in your function and that will work.

In fact, you are doing so in your code2. You innitialized sum as x+y

Answer (score 1):

the issue is because the local and global variable are of same name . so the function will give preference to local variable first . since the local variable is not assigned it gives the error  local variable is not assigned.

we can solve this issue by following ways:
1. use global keyword in the function 
2. keep names different.
3. use function  globals()

thanks