# Order in which the code compiles - Python

Tags: python, memory-management, compilation

*ALERT: Beginner's problem*

**Here is the question:**
Two players are given the same string, ex: "BANANA"
For each sub-string that can be formed starting with a vowel adds a score of 1 to player 1 else 1 to player 2 (repetitions allowed)
so finally: player's 1 score is 9 and player's 2 score is 12

```
vowels = "AEIOU"
player_1 = 0
player_2 = 0

def winner(user_string):
    for index, item in enumerate(user_string):
        if item in vowels:
            player_1 += len(user_string[index:])
        else:
            player_2 += len(user_string[index:])

    if player_1 > player_2:
        print("Ply 1 won")
    else:
        print("Ply 2 won")

winner("BANANA")
```

but it is throwing an error as shown below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0uJY.png)

can someone please help me out with the issue. Is there any order of compilation that I need to learn here? Thank you

Comment: You should really copy/paste the error as text into your question, rather than using an image.

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python will be useful

Comment: Thank you for the support @EdChum

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of the scope of variables (here both: `player_1` and `player_2`). Check [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them).

So the correct approach would be to either move the initialization of the variables to the function or add:

```
global player_1
global player_2
```

at the beginning of the function `winner` body.

My preference is the first approach so the correct function is:

```
def winner(user_string):
    player_1 = player_2 = 0
    for index, item in enumerate(user_string):
        if item in vowels:
            player_1 += len(user_string[index:])
        else:
            player_2 += len(user_string[index:])

    if player_1 > player_2:
        print("Ply 1 won")
    else:
        print("Ply 2 won")
```