# Using variables in functions (Python)

Tags: python, global-variables

Given the following code:

```
U = [1,2,3]

def test():
    # global U
    u = U * 2
    print(u)
    # U = u

test()
print(U)
```

In this form prints(u) displays [1,2,3,1,2,3]. This means 'U' was read successfully in the function.

But if I uncomment the U = u line then I receive the following error message:

```
 u = U * 2 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'U' referenced before assignment
```

which I can only fix by uncommenting the 'global U' line. I dont understand this though. Previously u=U*2 worked just fine. Why is an error raised at u=U*2 if I uncomment a line below it?

EDIT: I dont think it is duplicate. My question is why do I see an error in a line which is unmodified. In my real code there are about 100 lines between 'u=U*2' and 'U=u' and it took me couple hours ro realize that the error is actually somehow caused by the 'U=u' line.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python

Comment: The line `global U` will fix your problem. It is fine that you found a minimal example of your bug. I can confirm that your problem is a duplicate of these or if you understand them you will also understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`U = ...` creates a local variable `U`. It doesn't matter where in the function this appears, at the beginning or the end, Python is resolving all those things when it parses the function body. It doesn't matter that there's a global variable `U` as well in this case, it is being shadowed by the local variable `U` appearing in the function body. So the problem boils down to you trying to do `U * 2` before you have defined `U`. You could call the variable anything else besides `U` for the same effect.

To clarify:

```
u = U * 2
U = u
```

This does not mean *read the global `U`, then create a local `U`.* By `U = ...` appearing *anywhere* inside the function body, Python reserves the name `U` as a local variable name. The same name cannot ambiguously refer to a global variable and in the next line to a local variable.

When you also add `global U`, you're clarifying for Python that the name `U` in the local function scope refers to the global variable `U` always.

When you omit `U = ...`, then there's no local variable of that name being created anywhere inside the function, and Python looks up the value of `U` from the surrounding scope when getting its value.

Comment: If i `print(locals())` just below the like `# global U` it shows empty dict. So it means that python has no idea about variable U, right?

Comment: You won't see it before you assign anything to it, yes.