# Python - UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment`

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, sqlite, local

I'm writing a Python 3.6 script that works with Tkinter and an SQLite 3 database, but I get this error:

`if "fImage" in globals() and not(fImage==None):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fImage' referenced before assignment`

The interested code is this:

```
from tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from tkinter import Toplevel, Tk
import sqlite3 as sql
def Salvataggio(mode,nome,cognome,sitoweb,email,idx):
    conn=sql.connect(os.path.join(path, fn_prof),isolation_level=None)
    c=conn.cursor()
    if mode=="add":
        if "fImage" in globals() and not(fImage==None):
            c.execute("INSERT INTO prof VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(len(prof.keys())+1,nome.get(),cognome.get(),fImage,sitoweb.get(),email.get()))
        else:                
            c.execute("INSERT INTO prof VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(len(prof.keys())+1,nome.get(),cognome.get(),"",sitoweb.get(),email.get()))
        del fImage
        wa.destroy()
    elif mode=="edit":
        if "fImage" in globals() and not(fImage==None):
            c.execute("""UPDATE prof
                      SET nome = '{}', cognome = '{}', imageURI='{}', web='{}', email='{}'
                      WHERE ID={}; """.format(nome.get(),cognome.get(),fImage,sitoweb.get(),email.get(),idx))
        else:                
            c.execute("""UPDATE prof
                      SET nome = '{}', cognome = '{}', web='{}', email='{}'
                      WHERE ID={}; """.format(nome.get(),cognome.get(),sitoweb.get(),email.get(),idx))
        del fImage
def selImmagine(bi):
    if not("fImage" in globals()):
        global fImage
    fImage=askopenfilename(filetypes=[(_("File Immagini"),"*.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.bmp *.gif *.psd *.tif *.tiff *.xbm *.xpm *.pgm *.ppm")])
    # other code...
```

Do you know how to solve this? The error results with the if and the elif in the salvataggio() function.
Thanks

Comment: Why use `if not ("fImage" in globals())`? Just unconditionally use `global fImage`. Also, the code you posted does not match the error that you claim you are getting. The error shows an `if` with two conditions, the code shows one condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximal cause of your error is:

```
del fImage
```

which works like assignment, it causes `fimage` to be treated as local. Therefore, you are getting an unbound-local error, which makes sense, since you never assign to `fImage` in the first place in `Salvataggio`

Anyway, yours is a special case of the typical `UnboundLocalError`, because it didn't involve assignment to the variable to make it get marked as local. A common cause [being a hidden assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python):

You get a plain name error if the variable is neither global nor local.

```
In [1]: def f():
   ...:     if x in {}:
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [2]: f()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0ec059b9bfe1> in <module>()
----> 1 f()

<ipython-input-1-80c063ba8db6> in f()
      1 def f():
----> 2     if x in {}:
      3         pass
      4

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

However, the `del` marks the name as local:

```
In [3]: def f():
   ...:     if x in {}:
   ...:         pass
   ...:     del x
   ...:

In [4]: f()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0ec059b9bfe1> in <module>()
----> 1 f()

<ipython-input-3-5453b3a29937> in f()
      1 def f():
----> 2     if x in {}:
      3         pass
      4     del x
      5

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

This is why your check:

```
if "fImage" in globals() and not(fImage==None):
```

is the line where it fails. I do not understand why you always are checking whether `fimage` is in `globals()`. Note, `'fimage' in globals()` can be true while `fimage` is a local name... hence the unbound *local*.

Answer (score 2):

Remove:

```
del fImage
```

parts, it tries to remove `fImage` whether or not it exists.

---

See below [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
def func():
    del variable_that_never_existed

func()
```