# Why UnboundLocalError doesn't occur with lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a question regarding a tutorial problem.

Write a function `make_monitored` that takes as input a function, `f`, that itself takes one input. The result returned by make_monitored is a third function, say mf, that keeps track of the number of times it has been called by maintaining an internal counter. If the input to mf is the special string `"how-many-calls?"`, then mf returns the value of the counter. If the input is the special string `"reset-count"`, then mf resets the counter to zero. For any other input, mf returns the result of calling f on that input and increments the counter.

I have the following solution which works, surprisingly.

```
def make_monitored(f):
    calls=[0]
    def helper(n):
        if n=="how-many-calls?":
            return calls[0]
        elif n=="reset-count":
            calls[0]=0 
        else:
            calls[0]+=1
            return f(n)
    return helper
```

I recalled reading about UnboundLocalError here: [UnboundLocalError in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python)

My question would be why won't `calls[0]+=1`  trigger that error? I made an assignation to a variable outside the local scope of the third function `helper` , and it seems a similar solution that uses instead `calls.append(1)` (the rest of the code correspondingly becomes `len(calls)` and `calls.clear()`) also bypasses that error.

Comment: Because you're mutating the object already bound to `calls`, not replacing it. Try `calls = [1]` instead of `calls[0] += 1` and you'll see the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so if object A is outside the local scope, and I modify object B bound to object A, it doesn't count as UnboundLocalError as long as I don't directly assign a value to object A?