# UnboundLocalError with Caesar Cipher program

Tags: python

Currently, I'm working on a Caesar Cipher program for my Computer Science class. I however don't know how to use user-defined functions in this situation. I keep receiving an UnboundLocalError

```
#user defined functions

def encrypt(message, distance):
    """Will take message and rotate it the distance, in order to create an encrypted message"""


    for ch in message:
        ordvalue = ord(ch)
        cipherValue = ordvalue + distance
        if cipherValue > ord("z"):
            cipherValue = ord("a") + distance - (ord("z") - ordvalue + 1)
        encryption += chr(cipherValue)
        return encryption

#input 

message = input("Enter word to be encrypted: ") #original message
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: ")) #distance letters will be moved

# test
fancy = encrypt(message, distance)

#encryption

print(fancy)
```

Comment: What's the exact error? Where is `encryption` declared?

Comment: Regardless of the error, you have `return` in a `for` loop which is basically pointless because it will immediately break out of the function. On another theme, the fact that your assignment is due on Monday is _your_ concern, not the concern of Stack Overflow or any other readers of this question. This is not a help desk to serve you, it's supposed to be a repository of general questions and answers helpful to all.

Comment: Your problem seems to be unrelated to *user defined functions*, its just unfinished code with some deficiencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't understand why UnboundLocalError occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/dont-understand-why-unboundlocalerror-occurs)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing variable `encryption` without declaring it. Declare it as an empty string before the `for` loop to prepare it for adding partial strings to it.

See more discussion in a related discussion on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/dont-understand-why-unboundlocalerror-occurs).

On another note, return statement in you function is indented in the `for` loop, which means it will exit the function after one iteration of the loop, making the loop pointless. This looks like a mistake and it should be indented one level less.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the UnboundLocalError is because you reference `encryption` before defining it when you write `encryption += chr(cipherValue)` since `encryption` is never defined in the first place. To fix this you can define it (as an empty string) at the start of your function.

Also you need to move the `return` statement out one block so that it goes after the loop, not inside of it.

Here's an example:

```
def encrypt(message, distance):
    """Will take message and rotate it the distance, in order to create an encrypted message"""
    encryption = ""
    for ch in message:
        ordvalue = ord(ch)
        cipherValue = ordvalue + distance
        if cipherValue > ord("z"):
            cipherValue = ord("a") + distance - (ord("z") - ordvalue + 1)
        encryption += chr(cipherValue)
    return encryption
```