# UnboundLocalError continues to pop up and i cant figure out why

Tags: python, scope

the terminal is outputting an error saying `local variable 'Listener' referenced before assignment`. I'm trying to import listener `from pynput.keyboard import Listener`

I've tried re-writing the program and changing about the import

```py
import os
import time
from threading import Thread, Timer

from mss import mss
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

class IntervalTimer(Timer):
    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

class Monitor:    
    def _on_press(self, K):
        with open("./log/keylogs/log.txt", "a")as f:
            f.write("{} \t\t {}\n".format(K, time.time()))    

    def _build_logs(self):
        if not os.path.exists("./logs"):
            os.mkdir("./logs")
            os.mkdir("./logs/screenshots")
            os.mkdir("./log/keylogger")

    def _keylogger(self):
        with Listener(on_press = self._on_press)as Listener:
            Listener.join()

    def _screenshot(self):
        sct = mss()
        sct.shot(output="./logs/screenshots/{}.png".format(time.time()))

    def run(self, interval = 1):
        self._build_logs()
        Thread(target=self._keylogger).start()
        IntervalTimer(interval, self._screenshot).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mon = Monitor()
    mon.run()
```

this is the error

```
    with Listener(on_press = self._on_press)as Listener:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Listener' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Try `with Listener(on_press = self._on_press)as listener:` and then keep using `listener` instead

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you redefine `Listener` in `_keylogger`. For an explanation, see [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) in the Python FAQ, or [Don't understand why UnboundLocalError occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9264763/4518341)

To fix it, just change the name of the `Listener` instance. Instances are normally written in all lowercase anyway.

```
with Listener(on_press=self._on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```