# UnboundLocalError in discord.py bot with coin system

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The directory is changed to the folder with the JSON file after importing everything like discord, os, json, etc.

```
@client.command()
async def gift(ctx,*, member: discord.Member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(users, f)

        await update_data(users, discord.member)
        await add_coin(users, discord.member, 1)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            users = json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['coins'] = 0

async def add_coin(users, user, coin):
    users[user.id]['coins'] += coin
    await client.send(channel,'{} has {} coins'.format(user.id, coin))
```

When the command is run, the bot gives an error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable "users" referenced before assignment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see you have a problem with `users = json.load(users, f)`. This should be `users = json.load(f)`. Try it! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/dont-understand-why-unboundlocalerror-occurs

Comment: In the future, please show the full traceback of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jaideep Shekhar answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694025/unbound-local-error-in-discord-py-bot-with-coin-system#comment105543642_59694025), `users` is referenced in the call to `json.load` before it's assigned.
[`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) only accepts a single positional argument, so you'll want to pass only the file pointer.