# Why are global variables accessible in some functions but not others?

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

Below is a small section of code that illustrates my question:

```
index = 0
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def b():
    print(index)
    print(a)
def c():
    print(index)
    print(a)
    while a[index] < 3:
        index += 1

b()
c()
```

I get the following output:

```
0
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "global.py", line 14, in <module>
    c()
  File "global.py", line 8, in c
    print(index)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment
```

The function `b` printed `index` and `a` as expected. However, function `c` neither prints the two variables, nor do they seem to be accessible in the `while` loop after the print statements.

What is causing the two variables to be accessible in `b` but not in `c`?

Comment: You can read variables from a higher scope, but as soon as you change them it gets tricky.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/dont-understand-why-unboundlocalerror-occurs-closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the difference:

```
index += 1
```

If you *set/change* a variable *anywhere* in the function, Python assumes it's a local rather than a global, *everywhere* in the function. That's the difference between your two functions, `b()` doesn't try to change it.

To fix this, you can just out:

```
global index
```

at the top of your `c()` function, which tells it to assume global no matter what. You may want to do that in `b()` as well, just to be explicit and consistent.

Or, you could find a way to do this *without* globals, which is probably preferable :-) Something like:

```
index = 0
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def b(idx, arr):
    print(idx)
    print(arr)

def c(idx, arr):
    print(idx)
    print(arr)
    while arr[idx] < 3:
        idx += 1
    return idx

b(index, a)
index = c(index, a)
```