# UnboundLocalError when trying to delete multiple list elements by index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a task list program Python. In my function `delete_task`, I've asked the user to input a string to give the indices of the tasks they'd like to delete. It will accept inputs like `1`, `1, 2`, `1-3`, `1-2, 4, 5` and so on, and then produce the `indices` list, e.g. the input `1-3, 5` will produce the list `[1, 2, 3, 5]`.

Of course, the problem with trying to delete items from a list this way is that the indices will change every time I remove an item. So I tried using a list comprehension to pick out the items in my task list which are not in my `indices` list.

```
def delete_task():
    display_list()
    indices = parse_range(input("\nEnter the task number[s] to delete: "))
    deltodo = [task for index, task in enumerate(todo, 1) if index not in indices]
    todo = deltodo
```

`todo` is a list of class objects. Here's the class declaration:

```
class Task():
    t = ""
    checked = False
    def __init__(self, t, checked):
        self.t = t
        self.checked = checked

global todo
todo = []
```

The problem occurs on the list comprehension, the program throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "todo.py", line 123, in <module>
    delete_task()
  File "todo.py", line 38, in delete_task
    deltodo = [task for index, task in enumerate(todo, 1) if index not in indices]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'todo' referenced before assignment
```

According to [this link](https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/680/solving-python-error-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-x-referenced-before-assignment/#:%7E:text=UnboundLocalError%20can%20be%20solved%20by,explicitly%20declare%20the%20variable%20global.&text=Variable%20x%27s%20scope%20in%20function,and%20it%20will%20be%206.), one solution to this problem is to make sure that the variable is global. I know that this is bad practice etc., but as the program is only for me I tried doing it. But it still returns the error above.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how to avoid this error.

**EDIT:** In response to mkrieger1, I thought it was worth noting that I have used `todo` in other functions without declaring it global, and it hasn't caused any problems. For example, here's my `add_task` function.

```
def add_task():
    clear()
    display_list()
    t = Task(input("\nTask: "), False)
    todo.append(t)
    save_list()
```

If I need to declare `todo` globally in each function, why does it work here but not in `delete_task`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't understand why UnboundLocalError occurs (closure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/dont-understand-why-unboundlocalerror-occurs-closure)

Comment: `todo` already is a global variable in your case. If you want to assign to it inside `delete_task` you need to write `global todo` *inside `delete_task`*, as explained in the article you have linked.

Comment: @mkrieger1, Your explanation makes sense, but I'm wondering why I haven't encountered problems in any of my other functions. I've edited a further explanation.

Comment: You only need to use the `global` keyword if you want to *assign* to a global variable.

Comment: @Lou You can append or use global variables outside of their scope. You just can't modify them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've added `global todo` at the beginning of the function and that's solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `global todo` statement at the top of the `delete_task` function. The `global` keyword allows you to modify the variable outside of the current scope, so you must put that inside the scope you want to modify it in. In this case it's in `delete_task`.

```py
def delete_task():
    global todo
    display_list()
    indices = parse_range(input("\nEnter the task number[s] to delete: "))
    deltodo = [task for index, task in enumerate(todo, 1) if index not in indices]
    todo = deltodo
```

**EDIT**: Replying to your question that why the error doesn't come in other functions, you can append or use global variables outside of their scope. You just can't modify them.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) link for more information about the global keyword