# double calculation in function

Tags: python

**Why does this function doesn't work?**

```
int_myApples = 4    
int_yourApples = 13    
int_TotalApples = int_myApples + int_yourApples    

def giveApple():    
    int_yourApples += 1    
    int_myApples -=1    
    
giveApple()     
    
print("If I give you one of my apples,you have {} and I have {} apples.".format(int_yourApples,int_myApples))`
```

**If I do the same without putting it into a function it just works.**

```
int_yourApples += 1    
int_myApples -=1    
    
print("If I give you one of my apples, you have {} and I have {} apples.".format(int_yourApples,int_myApples))
```

**Any reason why?**

Comment: You haven't mentioned the error message you get, but if you searched it on here you would find lots of questions and answers explaining it.

Comment: Duplicate: [Don't understand why UnboundLocalError occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9264763/4518341)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A function needs global variables to call outside of the function, you can do it like this.

```
def giveApple():    
    global int_yourApples
    global int_myApples

    int_yourApples += 1    
    int_myApples -=1
```

Comment: This works, but [global variables are generally bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/4518341), so it would be better to mention alternatives first.

Comment: "For smaller applications, global variables are not a problem." Though yes your point does have validity.

Comment: Small apps tend to grow into large apps if they're useful enough. So those globals tend to cause problems down the road.

Comment: Your point does have merit.