# a basic question about python(difference variables and lists outside a function)

Tags: python

```
age = 11

def agePrint():

    age += 1

    print(age)

agePrint()
```

--- This code makes an error. It is obvious. Because age is outside the function agePoint().
But... if age type is a list...

```
age = [11, 12, 13]

def agePrint():

    age[0] = 15

    print(age)

agePrint()
```

This code works well. I want to know the reason.
I am waiting for your answer.

Many thanks

Comment: `age +=` contains an *assignment to a variable*, `age[0] =` is just an object mutation, not a reassignment. Outer variables are always available to *read* inside nested functions, `print(age)` or `age[0]` works inside the function in any case. It's the assignment that breaks it. Read [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264845/476) for why.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour has to do with the variable `age` being an integer or a list.

The restriction involved goes like "a global variable can't be modified inside a function, unless explicitly allowed by using the keyword `global`". In the first case, `age` is of type `int`, so it stores the integer value as is. However, in the second case, `age` is of type `list`, so it actually stores the pointer or reference to a list-like object. When you change an element of that list, you're only changing an attribute of that object, but not the variable itself (`age` conserves its value). In order to change the variable, in that latter case, you would have to assign a different value directly or somehow try to change the pointer or reference.

This can be confusing if you don't know about object-oriented programming or you're not aware of python using objects, but basically all variables in python which aren't integers, floats or booleans are objects.

Comment: *Every* value is an object, even integers, floats and bools. However, there's simply no way to *mutate* them. They don't expose any methods that would allow you to *mutate* an int, hence you can only reassign them.