# Closure arguments visibility Python

Tags: python-3.x, scope, closures

I have function defined like this:

```
def foo(karg=None):
    def bar():
        print(karg)
        if karg is None:
            karg = None

    return bar

foo()()
```

Running above code results in following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xps/a.py", line 10, in <module>
    foo()()
  File "/home/xps/a.py", line 3, in bar
    print(karg)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'karg' referenced before assignment
```

If I delete if branch in above function, code runs just fine:

```
def foo(karg=None):
    def bar():
        print(karg)

    return bar

foo()()
```

Shouldn't `karg` be visible all throughout `bar()` function?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264845/16757174) answer your question? This question is also answered on the [Python official FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: It does. Thank you.