# Python throws UnboundLocalError when dealing with outer variables

Tags: python

```py
player_name = ''


def main():
    if not player_name:
        player_name = input('Please input your name')
    else:
        input('Your name is {}'.format(player_name))


main()
```

and it throws:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player_name' referenced before assignment.
```

why can't `main()` function reference out variables? thanks!

Comment: you need `global player_name` because the parser sees the variable as local otherwise, because you're assigning to it

Comment: why do you need to define it before ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't understand why UnboundLocalError occurs (closure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/dont-understand-why-unboundlocalerror-occurs-closure)

Comment: @SamBob  thanks, i think that answers my question. I was using this snippet in a bigger program which needs to manipulate global variables.