# Why isn't Python recognizing my declared variable as a global variable?

Tags: python, function, global, local

I am new to Python. I declared a variable named 'total' outside the function and then I called it inside my function called 'my_function'. But it is giving me an error because my variable 'total' is not global. Why is that? I thought variables declared outside were already considered global.

```
total = 1

def my_function(list):
    for i in list:
        total = total + 1
        print (total)

my_function([1,2,3])
```

[image: This is the error I am getting]

Comment: Since you're assigning to `total` in your function, Python considers it a local variable. But since you're also using `total` to compute the new value, Python correctly determines that it will not have a value at that point and you get this error. In most cases where you think you need a global variable, there's a better solution - but if you must use it here, add the line `global total` to the beginning of the function.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/dont-understand-why-unboundlocalerror-occurs-closure answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `global` keyword in your function

```py
total = 1

def my_function(list):
    global total
    for i in list:
        total = total + 1
        print(total)

my_function([1, 2, 3])
```

Output:

```py
2
3
4
```