# why do i keep getting this python error cost is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### i wrote this code i get an error say cost is not defined

```
print("============================================================\n"
      "                 Welcome to Pizza Store                              \n"
      "============================================================\n")
def welcomescreen():
    print("1) Menu for the Pizza")
    print("2) Order the Pizza")
    print("3) Exit the program")
    ch = input("Select from one of the above: ")
    return ch
def main():
    choice = welcomescreen()
    while choice != '3':
            # based on user choice add appropriate method
        if choice == '1':
            print("1. Pepperoni               9 AED\n2. Margherita              12 AED\n3. Vegetarian              15 AED\n4. Neapolitan              21 AED")
            ask = input("Do you want to go back to the main menu? yes/no : \n").lower()
            if ask == "yes":
                main()
            elif ask == "no":
                break
        elif choice == '2':
            n=int(input("Enter the number of pizzas to be ordered: "))
            kind=input("Enter the kind of Pizza: ")
            size=input("Enter the size of Pizza\n(Large (50 AED),Medium (40 AED), Small (30 AED) : ")
            if(size == "Large"):
                cost_size=n*50
            elif(size == "Medium"):
                cost_size=n*40
            elif(size == "Small"):
                cost_size = n*30
            if(kind == "Pepperoni"):
              cost= n*10
              pizza = 'Pepperoni'
            elif(kind== "Margherita" ):
                cost= n*15
                pizza = "Margherita"
            elif(kind == "Vegetarian" ):
                cost= n*20
                pizza = "Vegetarian"
            elif(kind== "Neapolitan"):
                cost= n*18
                pizza = "Neapolitan"
            d=input("Enter toppings: \n").split(" ")
            extra=0
            if(len(d)>3):
                 extra= n*3*(len(d)-3)
#final Bill
            print("---------------------Your BILL-----------------------\n")
            print("The Pizza kind :", kind)
            print("The size :", size)
            print("Number of pizzas :  x", n)
            print("Extra toppings :")
            for i in d:
                print(i,end=" ")
            print("\n")
            print("==========Breakdown of bill========== \n")
            print("Bill for pizza         : ", cost)
            print("Bill for size         : ",cost_size)
            print("Bill for extra toppings: ",extra)
            print("Total Bill             : ",cost+cost_size+extra)

        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Try again.")
        
        choice = welcomescreen()

    print("Thank you! Have a nice day :)")
main()
```

---

the error i get is:

## ============================================================
Welcome to Pizza Store

1. Menu for the Pizza
2. Order the Pizza
3. Exit the program
   Select from one of the above: 2
   Enter the number of pizzas to be ordered: 1
   Enter the kind of Pizza: pepperoni
   Enter the size of Pizza
   (Large (50 AED),Medium (40 AED), Small (30 AED) : large
   Enter toppings:
   pepperoni
   ---------------------Your BILL-----------------------

The Pizza kind : pepperoni
The size : large
Number of pizzas :  x 1
Extra toppings :
pepperoni

==========Breakdown of bill==========

```
Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
cannot access local variable 'cost' where it is not associated with a value
  File "C:\Users\mandoof1\Downloads\Pizza part A.py", line 57, in main
    print("Bill for pizza         : ", cost)
  File "C:\Users\mandoof1\Downloads\Pizza part A.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
```

what is supposed to happen is take the cost based on your input and give you the bill

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this UnboundLocalError occur (closure)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/why-does-this-unboundlocalerror-occur-closure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cost` is only defined if `kind` is one of the three strings you check against in your if/elifs. Specifically, I think whats happening is that you're putting in 'pepperoni' but you really want to put in 'Pepperoni' (notice the capitalization)

To handle this more generally, you probably want to:

1. `.lower()` the input `kind` and what you're checking against so you don't have to worry about capitalization
2. Have an `else` clause when checking kind, so that if the user puts in something unexpected you know about it.
3. Repeat these two fixes for the `size` input as well.

Comment: thanks it turns out python is way more case sensitive than i thought thanaks