# How to declare a global variable in Python correctly

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code that presented below with tic-tac-toe implementation. As far as I understand variable "player" is global one and it's value 'X' should be accessed from any place of the program.

```
board = [['_' for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
player = 'X'

def print_board():
    for row in board:
        print(row)

def check_win():
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] != '_':
            return board[i][0]
        if board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] != '_':
            return board[0][i]
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] != '_':
        return board[0][0]
    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] != '_':
        return board[0][2]
    return None

def greet():
    while True:
        print_board()
        print(f"Player {player}, make your move (row column): ")
        row, col = map(int, input().split())
        if board[row][col] != '_':
            print("Invalid move, try again.")
            continue
        board[row][col] = player
        winner = check_win()
        if winner:
            print_board()
            print(f"Player {winner} wins!")
            break
        if "_" not in [cell for row in board for cell in row]:
            print_board()
            print("Tie!")
            break
        player = 'X' if player == 'O' else 'O'

greet()
```

But as a result I got the error: `print(f"Player {player}, make your move (row column): ") UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player' referenced before assignment`. How to declare global variables in a correct way in Python?

What I'm doing wrong?

I expected the code of tic-tac-toe working correctly but it didn't. To resolve the issue I tried to change "player" scope and moved an assignment inside greet() method before infinite loop. It works perfect, but I have no clue why it didn't work before, as a global variable.

Comment: You mentioned ... *To resolve the issue I tried to change "player" scope and moved an assignment inside greet() method before infinite loop. It works perfect, but I have no clue why it didn't work before, as a global variable.*  Could you show snippet of this section of code that works. That will enrich your question.  Inbtw, you might simply have a scope problem

Answer (score 4):

You "declare" it outside the the functions as you did here. But you're missing the `global` keyword.

Then:

- If you only read its value inside a function, it's treated as a global variable.

  ```py
  variable_name = "old value"

  def function():
      print(variable_name)

  function()  # old value
  print(variable_name)  # old value
  ```
- Normally, if you write to it, it's treated as a local variable.

  ```py
  variable_name = "old value"

  def function():
      variable_name = "new value"
      print(variable_name)

  function()  # new value
  print(variable_name)  # old value
  ```
- To write to it as a global variable, add the `global` keyword in the function definition before using the variable.

  ```py
  variable_name = "old value"

  def function():
      global variable_name
      variable_name = "new value"
      print(variable_name)

  function()  # new value
  print(variable_name)  # new value
  ```

Source: https://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Answer (score 3):

If a function *assigns* to a variable name (which your `greet()` function does for the `player` variable), then that variable name is treated as local *everywhere* in the function, even if there is a global variable of the same name.

If you want the function to use the global variable, put this at the top of the function:

```
global player
```

By contrast, your `print_board()` function does not *assign* to a variable named `board`, therefore it is able to use that global variable without explicitly declaring `global board`.

Answer (score 1):

To declare a global variable you simply need to add a line above the declerration saying `global` followed by the name of the variable.

E.g:

```
global name
name = "daniel"
```

Comment: Answer is duplicated

Answer (score 0):

You 'declare' a variable player and assigned it a string value X.
`player = 'X'`

You then 'reference' this variable within a function that doesn't have the variable passed to it as argument).
If you go through the full error code you received, you'll note the offending line of code.
PS: you only paste the specific part of the error (which is fine though).

To resolve this, within the function `greet()`, simply declare `global player`

Pls, read more on UnboundLocalError, on local and global variables.
Also, do check a previous question with is incidentally a duplicate of another question! [Why does this UnboundLocalError occur (closure)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/why-does-this-unboundlocalerror-occur-closure)

[Additions]
With that said, I'll strongly recommend that you wrapped up your functions within a class. It'll come up handy in referencing your variables, assigning values to them, keeping state through `self`.
Also, give due thoughts to try, error handling especially around input(), and board assigning.

```py
board = [['_' for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
player = 'X'

def print_board():
    for row in board:
        print(row)

def check_win():
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] != '_':
            return board[i][0]
        if board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] != '_':
            return board[0][i]
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] != '_':
        return board[0][0]
    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] != '_':
        return board[0][2]
    return None

def greet():
    global player. ##add to resolve UnboundLocalError
    while True:
        print_board()
        print(f"Player {player}, make your move (row column): ")
        row, col = map(int, input().split())
        if board[row][col] != '_':
            print("Invalid move, try again.")
            continue
        board[row][col] = player
        winner = check_win()
        if winner:
            print_board()
            print(f"Player {winner} wins!")
            break
        if "_" not in [cell for row in board for cell in row]:
            print_board()
            print("Tie!")
            break
        player = 'X' if player == 'O' else 'O'

print(f'player outside greet() | {player}')
greet()
```